Apocalypse/ End Of The World/ Disappearance
(This is what I Remember: may not be 100% accurate) 
A Woman takes her younger brother to the store after visiting her (very) religious mother. While in the store her brother disappears leaving his clothes and backpack behind. 
She realizes that a lot of people disappeared the same way (her mother included), leaving behind the "unbelieving/bad" people of the earth. 
She tries to make contact with her dad and boyfriend? who are pilots on the same airplane. She helps them land the plane on an abandoned landing strip.
This movie was supposed to be the first of a series but I don't think it took off. It was based on a book series.

Production-wise, these seem to have made it further along in the series than you indicated, but  could it be Left Behind, by any chance?
Original series

Left Behind: The Movie (2000) Theatrical
Left Behind II: Tribulation Force (2002) Direct to video
Left Behind: World at War (2005) Direct to video

Reboot

Left Behind (2014) Theatrical

Spin-off series

Left Behind: Next Generation–Vanished (2016) Theatrical


Left Behind (film series)


Left Behind: The Next Generation?!  ROFL!  This made my day

Followed by Left Behind: Deep Space Nine. ;-)
